# Application.launch() issue in javaFX 2.0

Tags: java, javafx-2

In my code, I have used :

```
Application.launch(MyDesign.getClass(), null);
```

to run a UI of MyDesign from a seperate class.
When it calls `launch()`, it executes the constructor of `MyDesign` class. I have created a `MyDesign` object earlier and initialized its attributes. So I got a new object after calling `launch()`. I need to stop the calling its constructor when I call

```
Application.launch().
```

Your feed back is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't directly run already created Application through `Application.launch()`.

You can use next stub application and launch it instead:

```
public class Runner extends Application {

    @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       myDesignInstance.start(stage);
   }
}
```